# Pandas MemoryError with concat on relatively small excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, concatenation

I am merging 6 xlsx files, each a few MB. They generally have the same data, but some have some extra variables (which I want to preserve), and some also have unique names for the same variables. Below is the python code I wrote to try and accomplish the task, but I get a MemoryError (I saw in task manager, that it was taking up ~2GB of ram at the time). It doesn't make sense for this program to take much much than a couple hundred MB of RAM to me, considering the file sizes, so I'm hoping someone can point out where my error is.

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path

fpath = 'K:\\DATA\\python\\Mergingtest\\tess\\'

#Specify file locations and sheet names
data_headers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'TESS_Headers_2006-2015.xlsx'), sheetname='Sheet1', header=1)
data_07 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'TESS 2007.xlsx'), sheetname='Errors', header=0)
data_08 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'TESS 2008.xlsx'), sheetname='Errors', header=0)
data_09 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'TESS 2009.xlsx'), sheetname='Errors', header=0)
data_10 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'TESS 2010.xlsx'), sheetname='Sheet1', header=0)
data_11 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'TESS 2011.xlsx'), sheetname='Sheet1', header=0)
data_12_15 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'COPY_TESS 2012-2015 Master File.xlsx'), sheetname='Sheet1', header=0)

#Standardizing naming for equivalent variables from each file
data_headers.columns = ["fldErrorID", "fdSiteCaseID", "fdSiteID", "fdYear", "fdProvince", "fdAccessionNum", "fdDateEventOccurred", "fdDateStamp", "fdDiscoveredDuringSpecify", "fdDiscoveryDate", "fdPersonInvolvedSpecify", "fdProductRecordActionSpecify", "event1", "event2", "fdDiscoveryConsequenceEvent", "fdLocationCodeDiscovery", "fdLocationCodeOccurence", "fdDayOfWeekOccurred", "fdDiscoveredDuring", "fdDiscoveryTime", "fdPersonInvolved", "fdTimeEventOccurred", "fdDayOfWeekOccurredHoliday", "fdAdditionalTesting", "fdFloorClinicNotified", "fdOther", "fdProvincialID", "fdPatientSampleRecollected", "fdProductDestroyed", "fdProductRetrieved", "fdRecordCorrected", "fdSeverity", "fdNumberOfUnits", "fdProductType", "fdDiscovery", "fdProductDenied", "fdDiscoverersJob", "fdDiscoverersJobSpecify", "fdProductRecordAction", "fdNoAction", "fdClosed", "fldShareWithPHAC", "fdReviewedWithPersonInvolved", "fdBloodSupplierManufacurerNotifi", "cptr_delay2", "clin_lab_err", "sitegraded", "cptr_delay", "gen_code1", "disc_cnsq1", "cnsqnc_gen", "capacity1", "capacity", "severity1", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Describe the event", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Describe how the event was discovered", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Sub-location", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Sub-location", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Did the actual event harm the patient?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If event caused harm to patient, describe", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Was the near-miss event discovered because of a planned/unplanned detection procedure/process?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Discovery/Consequence code: Specify", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Actual Severity", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: What was the outcome of the event to the patient up to 30 days after it was discovered?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If patient died, did the consequence of the event play a role in death?", "Date Created", "Case State", "Site ID grading", "dvcq"]
data_07.columns = ["fldErrorID", "fdSiteCaseID", "fdProvince", "fdAccessionNum", "fdDateEventOccurred", "fdDateStamp", "fdDiscoveredDuringSpecify", "fdDiscoveryDate", "fdPersonInvolvedSpecify", "fdProductRecordActionSpecify", "fdYear", "event1", "event2", "fdDiscoveryConsequenceEvent", "fdLocationCodeDiscovery", "fdLocationCodeOccurence", "fdDayOfWeekOccurred", "fdDiscoveredDuring", "fdDiscoveryTime", "fdPersonInvolved", "fdTimeEventOccurred", "fdDayOfWeekOccurredHoliday", "fdAdditionalTesting", "fdFloorClinicNotified", "fdOther", "fdProvincialID", "fdPatientSampleRecollected", "fdProductDestroyed", "fdProductRetrieved", "fdRecordCorrected", "fdSiteID", "fdSeverity", "fdNumberOfUnits", "fdProductType", "fdDiscovery", "fdProductDenied", "fdDiscoverersJob", "fdDiscoverersJobSpecify", "fdProductRecordAction", "fdNoAction", "fdClosed", "fldShareWithPHAC"]
data_08.columns = ["fldErrorID", "fdSiteCaseID", "fdProvince", "fdAccessionNum", "sitegraded", "fdDateEventOccurred", "fdDateStamp", "fdDiscoveredDuringSpecify", "fdDiscoveryDate", "fdPersonInvolvedSpecify", "fdProductRecordActionSpecify", "fdYear", "event1", "gen_code1", "event2", "fdDiscoveryConsequenceEvent", "cnsqnc_gen", "fdLocationCodeDiscovery", "fdLocationCodeOccurence", "fdDayOfWeekOccurred", "fdDiscoveredDuring", "fdDiscoveryTime", "fdPersonInvolved", "fdTimeEventOccurred", "fdDayOfWeekOccurredHoliday", "fdAdditionalTesting", "fdFloorClinicNotified", "fdOther", "fdProvincialID", "fdPatientSampleRecollected", "fdProductDestroyed", "fdProductRetrieved", "fdRecordCorrected", "fdSiteID", "Site ID grading", "fdSeverity", "fdNumberOfUnits", "fdProductType", "fdDiscovery", "fdProductDenied", "fdDiscoverersJob", "fdDiscoverersJobSpecify", "fdProductRecordAction", "fdNoAction", "fdClosed", "fldShareWithPHAC"]
data_09.columns = ["fldErrorID", "fdSiteCaseID", "fdProvince", "sitegraded", "fdAccessionNum", "fdDateEventOccurred", "fdDateStamp", "fdDiscoveredDuringSpecify", "fdDiscoveryDate", "fdPersonInvolvedSpecify", "fdProductRecordActionSpecify", "fdYear", "event1", "gen_code1", "event2", "fdDiscoveryConsequenceEvent", "fdLocationCodeDiscovery", "fdLocationCodeOccurence", "fdDayOfWeekOccurred", "fdDiscoveredDuring", "fdDiscoveryTime", "fdPersonInvolved", "fdTimeEventOccurred", "fdDayOfWeekOccurredHoliday", "fdAdditionalTesting", "fdFloorClinicNotified", "fdOther", "fdProvincialID", "fdPatientSampleRecollected", "fdProductDestroyed", "fdProductRetrieved", "fdRecordCorrected", "fdSiteID", "fdSeverity", "fdNumberOfUnits", "fdProductType", "fdDiscovery", "fdProductDenied", "fdDiscoverersJob", "fdDiscoverersJobSpecify", "fdProductRecordAction", "fdNoAction", "fdClosed", "fldShareWithPHAC"]
data_10.columns = ["fldErrorID", "fdSiteCaseID", "fdProvince", "fdAccessionNum", "sitegraded", "fdDateEventOccurred", "fdDateStamp", "fdDiscoveredDuringSpecify", "fdDiscoveryDate", "cptr_delay", "fdPersonInvolvedSpecify", "fdProductRecordActionSpecify", "fdYear", "event1", "gen_code1", "dvcq", "event2", "fdDiscoveryConsequenceEvent", "fdLocationCodeDiscovery", "fdLocationCodeOccurence", "fdDayOfWeekOccurred", "fdDiscoveredDuring", "fdDayOfWeekOccurredHoliday", "fdAdditionalTesting", "fdFloorClinicNotified", "fdOther", "fdProvincialID", "fdPatientSampleRecollected", "fdProductDestroyed", "fdProductRetrieved", "fdRecordCorrected", "fdSiteID", "capacity1", "capacity", "severity1", "fdSeverity", "fdNumberOfUnits", "fdProductType", "fdDiscovery", "fdProductDenied", "fdDiscoverersJob", "fdNoAction", "fdClosed", "fdDiscoveryTime", "fdReviewedWithPersonInvolved", "fdTimeEventOccurred", "cptr_delay2", "clin_lab_err"]
data_11.columns = ["fldErrorID", "fdSiteCaseID", "fdProvince", "fdAccessionNum", "fdDateEventOccurred", "fdDateStamp", "fdDiscoveredDuringSpecify", "fdDiscoveryDate", "fdPersonInvolvedSpecify", "fdProductRecordActionSpecify", "fdYear", "event1", "event2", "fdDiscoveryConsequenceEvent", "fdLocationCodeDiscovery", "fdLocationCodeOccurence", "fdDayOfWeekOccurred", "fdDiscoveredDuring", "fdDiscoveryTime", "fdPersonInvolved", "fdTimeEventOccurred", "fdDayOfWeekOccurredHoliday", "fdAdditionalTesting", "fdFloorClinicNotified", "fdOther", "fdProvincialID", "fdPatientSampleRecollected", "fdProductDestroyed", "fdProductRetrieved", "fdRecordCorrected", "fdSiteID", "fdSeverity", "fdNumberOfUnits", "fdProductType", "fdDiscovery", "fdProductDenied", "fdDiscoverersJob", "fdDiscoverersJobSpecify", "fdProductRecordAction", "fdNoAction", "fdClosed", "fldShareWithPHAC"]
data_12_15.columns = ["fldErrorID", "fdSiteCaseID", "fdSiteID", "fdYear", "fdProvince", "fdAccessionNum", "fdDateEventOccurred", "fdDateStamp", "fdDiscoveredDuringSpecify", "fdDiscoveryDate", "fdPersonInvolvedSpecify", "fdProductRecordActionSpecify", "event1", "event2", "fdDiscoveryConsequenceEvent", "fdLocationCodeDiscovery", "fdLocationCodeOccurence", "fdDayOfWeekOccurred", "fdDiscoveredDuring", "fdDiscoveryTime", "fdPersonInvolved", "fdTimeEventOccurred", "fdDayOfWeekOccurredHoliday", "fdAdditionalTesting", "fdFloorClinicNotified", "fdOther", "fdProvincialID", "fdPatientSampleRecollected", "fdProductDestroyed", "fdProductRetrieved", "fdRecordCorrected", "fdSeverity", "fdNumberOfUnits", "fdProductType", "fdDiscovery", "fdProductDenied", "fdDiscoverersJob", "fdDiscoverersJobSpecify", "fdProductRecordAction", "fdNoAction", "fdClosed", "fldShareWithPHAC", "fdReviewedWithPersonInvolved", "fdBloodSupplierManufacurerNotifi", "cptr_delay2", "clin_lab_err", "sitegraded", "cptr_delay", "gen_code1", "disc_cnsq1", "cnsqnc_gen", "capacity1", "capacity", "severity1", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Describe the event", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Describe how the event was discovered", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Sub-location", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Sub-location", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Did the actual event harm the patient?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If event caused harm to patient, describe", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Was the near-miss event discovered because of a planned/unplanned detection procedure/process?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Discovery/Consequence code: Specify", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Actual Severity", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: What was the outcome of the event to the patient up to 30 days after it was discovered?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If patient died, did the consequence of the event play a role in death?", "Date Created", "Case State"]

concat = (pd.concat([data_headers,data_07,data_08,data_09,data_10,data_11,data_12_15]))
#specify column order to prevent default alphabetical-ordering
concat = concat[["fldErrorID", "fdSiteCaseID", "fdSiteID", "fdYear", "fdProvince", "fdAccessionNum", "fdDateEventOccurred", "fdDateStamp", "fdDiscoveredDuringSpecify", "fdDiscoveryDate", "fdPersonInvolvedSpecify", "fdProductRecordActionSpecify", "event1", "event2", "fdDiscoveryConsequenceEvent", "fdLocationCodeDiscovery", "fdLocationCodeOccurence", "fdDayOfWeekOccurred", "fdDiscoveredDuring", "fdDiscoveryTime", "fdPersonInvolved", "fdTimeEventOccurred", "fdDayOfWeekOccurredHoliday", "fdAdditionalTesting", "fdFloorClinicNotified", "fdOther", "fdProvincialID", "fdPatientSampleRecollected", "fdProductDestroyed", "fdProductRetrieved", "fdRecordCorrected", "fdSeverity", "fdNumberOfUnits", "fdProductType", "fdDiscovery", "fdProductDenied", "fdDiscoverersJob", "fdDiscoverersJobSpecify", "fdProductRecordAction", "fdNoAction", "fdClosed", "fldShareWithPHAC", "fdReviewedWithPersonInvolved", "fdBloodSupplierManufacurerNotifi", "cptr_delay2", "clin_lab_err", "sitegraded", "cptr_delay", "gen_code1", "disc_cnsq1", "cnsqnc_gen", "capacity1", "capacity", "severity1", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Describe the event", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Describe how the event was discovered", "SECTION A - DISCOVERY INFORMATION: Sub-location", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Sub-location", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Did the actual event harm the patient?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If event caused harm to patient, describe", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Was the near-miss event discovered because of a planned/unplanned detection procedure/process?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Discovery/Consequence code: Specify", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: Actual Severity", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 1", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 2", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 3", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Product type - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product destroyed, provide products: Number of units - 4", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 5", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 6", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 7", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Product type - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Name of product: Specify - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If product denied, provide products: Number of units - 8", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: What was the outcome of the event to the patient up to 30 days after it was discovered?", "SECTION B - OCCURRENCE INFORMATION: If patient died, did the consequence of the event play a role in death?", "Date Created", "Case State", "Site ID grading", "dvcq"]]

concat.to_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'Merge_Output.xlsx'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try instead

```
data_07 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'TESS 2007.xlsx'), sheetname='Errors') 
data_08 = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(fpath, 'TESS 2008.xlsx'), sheetname='Errors')
#keep headers for all xls files

concat =pd.concat([data_07,data_08], axis = 0) 
#remove data headers and add axis = 0

#get rid of individual files
del data_07
del data_08
```

Comment: So this succeeded, but it still climbed to several hundred MB of RAM usage. Is that normal? The files are just a couple MB each, but contain ~10k rows.

Comment: you should delete the single dataframe afterwards. See edited code

Comment: and then merge I merge 09 into the new 07-08 dataframe, and so on? So I'll basically have a loop where I add each file on one at a time?

Comment: nope, you can `concat` as many dataframes as you want at once. it is just for readability that I only chose two. Load everything as described and then `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis = 0)` etc

Comment: Ah, I thought that doing two at a time was your point. I'm not clear on what you changed to reduce memory usage then.

Comment: keeping the column names in the files and adding `axis = 0` bro, so that `concat` can work properly

Comment: I believe it defaults to axis=0 anyway. and I need to specify the column names here because the names in the source-files aren't all matching correctly.